# Does not displaying my input in mySQL workbench (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to connect my code (which i write in intellij) with mySQL workbench and it is connected as well but it is not displaying my output on the workbench.
I am providing this code but it throws exceptions and does not displaying my input to the workbech.

**DBMS SETUP**

```
        try {
            Connection connection = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students", "ishabhutto", "");
            if (connection != null)
             System.out.println("Connected");
            PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement("insert into studentdata values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            stm.setString(1,txt1.getText()); //Name
            stm.setString(2,txt2.getText()); //FatherName
            stm.setString(3, group.toString()); //Radio Button - male/female
            stm.setString(4,String.valueOf(pass.getPassword())); //Password Field
            stm.setString(5,txt4.getText()); //phone num
            stm.setString(6, txt6.getText()); //email
            stm.setString(7, City1.getActionCommand());  //ComboBox - Name of cities
            int row = stm.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(row);
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: which exceptions? can you post a log? and btw even if your code would run properly it won´t show up in your workbench console or the like if thats what you expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1